# Scanning numbers from a file into a two dimentional array

Tags: c

I am new to programming so I apologize if I mess up on anything.

So I am trying to scan a file with multiple lines of numbers and put them into a two dimensional array. I've tried looking at other questions relating to this and nothing has worked so far.

So I have tried using nested loops to scan the array and put the numbers inside but nothing seems to happen.
Inside the txt file is as follows:

```
0 7 9 4 0 0 8 0 4 5 0 1 
0 2 4 0 0 0 1 6 2 8 6 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0 8 5 6 8 0 7 
0 5 1 0 0 0 1 3 8 1 0 1
```

Every 12th number is a new line.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 12
#define ROW 4
#define COL 12
void
barcodeArray(int barcode[ROW][COL])
{
  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  FILE* f = fopen("q5_input.txt","r");
  if(f == NULL)
  {
    printf("no such file.");
  }
  for(int k = 0; k < ROW; k++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
    {
      fscanf(f, "%1d", &barcode[k][j]);
      printf("%ls", &barcode[k][j]);
    }
  }
  fclose(f);
}
int
main(void)
{
  int barcode[ROW][COL];
  barcodeArray;
}
```

The printf inside the for loops is just reading back the numbers as it inputs the numbers in the array. As the code is it compiles but does nothing.

Comment: You are not passing any parameters to barcodeArray

Comment: `printf("%ls", &barcode[k][j]);` looks very suspect. I suggest `printf("%d", barcode[k][j]);` Also `if(f == NULL)` you need to `return` or `exit(1)` not carry on reading the file. Please take notice of the several compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane when I change it to %d I get a compiling error and it says it needs to be %ls. After I changed the calling of the function it prints something but its very odd looking.

Comment: You need to remove the `&` from `&barcode[k][j]`. Use `printf("%d", barcode[k][j]);` But not from the `fscanf` line.

Comment: `printf("no such file.");` is the canonical example of a bad error message.  When the file exists, but you don't have permission to read it, the error message should say that.  Also, error messages belong on stderr. `perror("q5_input.txt")`

Comment: "but does nothing." --> `barcodeArray;` does not _call_ the function.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56995032/2410359

Answer (score 1):

You must call your function with argument `barcodeArray(barcode);`

Edit : If you are not sure of the size of the array you can take a look at dynamically allocated variables. This is an important part of C programming

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. I think using freopen() is easier and hassle free. It enables you to use same I/O functions that you use for console I/O operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 12
#define ROW 4
#define COL 12
void barcodeArray()
{
    int barcode[ROW][COL];//This can be declared inside the function.
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    FILE* f=freopen("q5_input.txt","r",stdin);
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("no such file.\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < ROW; k++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&barcode[k][j]);
            printf("%d ",barcode[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
int main(void)
{
    barcodeArray();
}
```

Additionally if you want to output it in a file you can do the following in the main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);
    barcodeArray();
}
```

Comment: Why have you moved the array out of `main` and what is the reason for `freopen`? These changes make it easier to answer, but also change the OP's intent. Also, a reason for the `%1d` is so that it won't matter if the input data is not space-separated.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could redirect a file handle to stdin